# Example application using HDFS+Map Reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, hdfs, hiveql

I have an academic course "Middleware" which covers different aspects of Distributed Software Systems including introduction to topics like [tag:Distributed File system]. This also involves introduction to [hbase](/questions/tagged/hbase),[hadoop](/questions/tagged/hadoop),[mapreduce](/questions/tagged/mapreduce),[hiveql](/questions/tagged/hiveql),[piglatin](/questions/tagged/piglatin).
I want to know, can I have a small project which tries to integrate above technologies. For starters, I am aware of [vm](/questions/tagged/vm) provided by [cloudera](/questions/tagged/cloudera) for having a feel of [hadoop](/questions/tagged/hadoop) and playing around using Eclipse.
I was thinking on lines of implementing an application which accepts stream of events as an input, Analyses this and gives an output.

I have both [windows](/questions/tagged/windows)/[linux](/questions/tagged/linux) on my machine with [i7](/questions/tagged/i7) procoessor and 4Gb Ram.

Please let me know how to get started with everything and any suggestions for simple example application are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2013/03/analyse-tweets-using-flume-hadoop-and.html) is a blog post on analyzing Tweets using Hive/HDFS. And [here](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2013/03/clickstream-analysis-using-pig-and-hive.html) is a blog post on performing Clickstream analytics using Pig and Hive.

Check some of the Big Data use cases [here](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/p/usecases.html) and try to solve an interesting problem.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the links. Will check them.